# How do you gunzip a file and keep the .gz file?

Tags: linux, gunzip, gz

The default behavior of gunzip is to delete the .gz file after it decompresses.

How do I prevent it from deleting the file??

If this functionality is not included then is there an alternative program that allows this?

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04

Comment: use the following command: gunzip -k

Comment: what gunzip has -k option? I see no one.

Comment: @Znik, *gzip/gunzip* version 1.6 and higher [has the option `-k`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gzip.git/commit/?id=0192f02e26ac9fa0a27ed177263ee3ea73d5e95c).

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
gzcat x.txt.gz >x.txt
```

The `gzcat` command is equivalent to `gunzip -c` which simply writes the output stream to `stdout`. This will leave the compressed file untouched. So you can also use:

```
gunzip -c x.txt.gz >x.txt
```

Note that on some systems gzcat is also known as `zcat` so run like this instead:

```
zcat x.txt.gz >x.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Growing up with pkunzip in DOS I find it so strange that there isn't an option to keep the file.  Especially with a tool like gzip being so widely used... just weird.

Comment: FYI, I actually don't have gzcat.  Neither my local system or the system I was ssh'ed into.  So, I have to use gunzip -c

Comment: it's probably just zcat on your system.

Comment: An additional option to keep the file would be nice indeed. For example, b(un)zip2 uses similar syntax and allows to simply add `-k` to keep the original file.

Comment: You can also add the line alias gzcat="gunzip -c" to your .bashrc

Comment: @Sen: pkunzip is more directly comparable to tar -xzf <filename.tar.gz>; it extracts multiple files from a compressed file, and does not remove the compressed file.   In *NIX systems, the concepts of "bundle multiple files together" and "compress data" aren't conflated like they are with .zip.  This means that when new compression systems come along, we don't have to reinvent/reimplement the "bundle multiple files together" code/logic.

Comment: Let me clarify @JamesKingsbery where the line starts and ends `alias gzcat="gunzip -c"` ... Of course, I don't mind just using `zcat`. Less typing, more energy efficient ;)

Comment: While this answer did help me, I still want to punish the guy who designed this command and decided that the destructive behavior should be the default..

Comment: @schnaader looks like gunzip supports a --keep option as of version 1.6...

Comment: Ah, thanks Jacob! @paxdiablo, could you edit the answer so it gives an example of the -k function? (http://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=7623 , paragraph "New features")

Comment: This procedure doesn't work when begin of file is damaged.

Comment: This is particularly painful if you need to gunzip a bunch of files in a dir. Easy enough to use loop but then it gets messy dropping the .gz off the end of the filename

Answer (score 69):

You can use the `-c` option of gunzip which writes the output to stdout, and then pipe it to the file of your choice:

```
gunzip -c compressed-file.gz > decompressed-file
```

More details on the [manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=gunzip&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+7.2-RELEASE&format=html).

Comment: By the way, note that the man page referred to above lists a -k option, which means keep input files. Maybe this works on the BSD version, but it doesn't on mine, so the -c solution seems to be the correct one.

Answer (score 45):

A simpler solution is to just use gunzip as a filter like this:

```
gunzip < myfile.gz > myfile
```

Comment: I think this is the cleanest way since `gunzip` never knows what file it's getting, all it sees is a stream of data, so can't possibly alter the original file.

Comment: It may be worth noting that you can also pipe the output, like: `gunzip < database.sql.gz | mysql -uroot -p`

Answer (score 21):

```
gzip -dk myfile.gz
```

OR

```
gunzip -k myfile.gz
```

Comments:

> ```
>    -k --keep    Keep (don't delete) input files during compression or decompression.
> ```

Comment: which version of gunzip are you using? gzip 1.5 from GNU has not the -k option

Comment: gzip: invalid option -- 'k'

Comment: @RhoPhi gzip and gunzip version: 1.10 , I use git bash (MINGW64) in windows

Comment: @Putnik I use 1.10

Answer (score 13):

If it's actually a tarball (.tgz or .tar.gz extension), then instead of redirecting to file like all of the answers so far, you'll want to pipe it to tar, like so:

```
gunzip -c myfile.tar.gz | tar xvf -
```

so that you get the actual contents.

Comment: or just do: tar xzvf myfile.tar.gz

Comment: true, but only if you have GNU tar. The one that comes with Solaris, for example, doesn't support the z option.

Comment: @JoakimElofsson deserves a medal !

Answer (score 5):

Use the `-c` option to uncompress the file to stdout. It will not touch the original file.

```
gunzip -c myfile.gz > myfile
```

Answer (score 2):

Gnu tar can read gzip files: `tar -zxsvf myfile.tar.gz` or `tar -jxzvf myfile.tar.bz2` for bzipped tar files.