# How to decompress the *.TGZ file without changing the orginal file?

Tags: unix, java, zip, gzip, gunzip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you gunzip a file and keep the .gz file ?](https://superuser.com/questions/45650/how-do-you-gunzip-a-file-and-keep-the-gz-file)

I decompress the file using following command:

```
gunzip -f  test.TGZ
```

This gave me test.tar file but I lost the test.TGZ file. Is there anyway to keep the original file?

EDIT & Update :
     I am calling the decompress commands through a Java program. The TGZ file contains at least  1 image file, 1 text file and 1 video file.

Java method : execute the command

```
private static InputStream executeCommand(String command, File workingDir)
        throws Exception {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec(command, null, workingDir);
    int exitValue = -1;
    try {
        exitValue = process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
    }

    if (exitValue != 0) {
        InputStream errStream = process.getErrorStream();
        String errMessage = null;
        if (errStream.available() > 0) {
            byte[] errOutput = new byte[errStream.available()];
            errStream.read(errOutput);
            errMessage = new String(errOutput);
        }

        throw new Exception(
                "Error in ExtractTGZFileTest.executeCommand(command=\""
                        + command + "\") - " + errMessage);
    }

    return process.getInputStream();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        if (args.length == 2 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("tgz")) {
            String archiveName = args[1];
            String tarFilnme = archiveName.substring(0, archiveName
                    .length()
                    - ".tgz".length())
                    + ".tar";
            String gzipCommand = "gzip -c -d " + archiveName + " > "
                    + tarFilnme;
            InputStream is = ExtractTGZFileTest.executeCommand(gzipCommand,
                    null);
        } else if (args.length == 2 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("tgz1")) {
            String archiveName = args[1];
            String gzipCommand = "gzip  --decompress --name --verbose "
                    + archiveName;
            InputStream is = ExtractTGZFileTest.executeCommand(gzipCommand,
                    null);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Usage: command <file1> ");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.out.println("DONE");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
}
```

**Solution : Currently, I copy the TGZ file to temporary location and working with that file.**

Comment: Looks like a post for SuperUser

Comment: Au contraire (it does not belong on SU): a relevant part of handling open source programs is knowing how to handle compressed tar files - a part of programming.

Comment: If we take away the programming part, this is a duplicate in here: http://superuser.com/questions/45650/how-do-you-gunzip-a-file-and-keep-the-gz-file

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
gzip -c -d test.tgz > test.tar
```

The '-c' option means write to standard output (rather than modifying the input file); the '-d' option means 'decompress'.

You can also use:

```
gunzip -c test.tgz > test.tar
```

If you have a modern enough version of GNU 'tar', you can simply use:

```
tar -xf test.tgz
```

If you have a slightly older version, you need to specify the compression program:

```
tar -xzf test.tgz
```

On those versions, you can use 'bzip2' too:

```
tar -xf test.tar.bz2 --use-compress-program=bzip2
```

(On more modern versions, option '-j' can be used to create a bzip2-compressed tar file; the unwrap code determines the correct decompressor automatically.)

Comment: Thanks lot, I will try these command through my program.

Comment: for "gunzip -c test.tgz > test.tar" command : program hangs when it trying to exec command

Comment: @Thillakan: That's because you cannot call "exec" with a redirect (the > symbol). You could either capture the output of the gunzip call (using `popen` or setting up pipes yourself) or use one of the tar commands instead. If you don't care about when/if the program exists, you can use system("gunzip -c test.tgz > test.tar") since the system function accepts the redirect symbol.

Comment: @Isak, Thanks to clear up the issue. I am going to stick with my current approach. It is easy for me :) .

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to decompress a GZipped file through Java, you may wish to consider using the [java.util.zip.ZipFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class. If you pass this class a File reference to a zip file, you can iterate through your entries and access them as InputStreams, like so:

```
String archiveName = args[1];
ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(archiveName);
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zf.entries();
ZipEntry nextElement = entries.nextElement();       
InputStream inputStream = zf.getInputStream(nextElement);
// use it: read data, serialise back to file, whatever
```

Comment: This class handles PK-Zip format, not gzip format.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jonathan Leffler, this is a java programmer asking how to access a compressed archive from his/her java program. The fact that it's a novice programmer, trying to do it the wrong way (through the OS), doesn't change that fact that this is a programming question that belongs on StackOverflow.

To answer the original question, doctorruss is correct in suggesting the use of a class. To access a .tar, .tar.gz or .tgz file, you should use a library capable of accessing tar archives. [The package com.ice.tar implements a tar archive io package](http://www.trustice.com/java/tar/), and *it is possible to combine this package with the java.util.zip package to handle .tar.gz files*. You can either download directly, or find it in org.apache.tools.tar which is now part of ant.jar.